# Как сделать, чтобы на моем сайте выполнялись скрипты, даже когда меня нет на сайте?

Tags: javascript, php, cron, auto

Вопрос, наверное, глупый, но все таки.

Мне необходимо, чтобы на моем сайте выполнялись js и php скрипты, без присутствия на нем. То есть, чтобы эти скрипты работали 24/7.

Пример: Я получаю данные по API, и отслеживаю изменения там. Если есть какие-то изменения, то на сайте выполняется определенный скрипт, который отправляет сообщение в телеграм. Все работает, только когда я присутствую на сайте.

Как быть, чтобы работали скрипты без моего присутствия на сайте? Может есть какие-то сервисы, имитирующие присутствие пользователя на странице 24/7, или что-то такое подобное?

Comment: В вашем вопросе присутствует тег "#cron". Что мешает запускать ваши задания в нем?

Comment: js скрипты так запустить не получится потому что js исполняется браузером. да и не думаю что для задачи которую вы описали он вообще нужен. отправлять сообщения в телеграм можно и через php для этого есть пакеты, погугли. ну и как сказал @NoSkill действительно что мешает написать этот php скрипт и запускать его через крон?

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Просто хотел узнать, есть ли еще какие-то способы, как можно реализовать мою задачу.

Comment: @midnightelf18 сообщения в телеграм в любом случае отправляются через бэкенд

Comment: Другие способы есть. На сайте могут присутствовать десктопные приложения, на пример AddNews